# PHP get json object name

Tags: php

I have json array like that

```
{
  "STATUS": "SUCCESS",
  "MESSAGE": "",
  "DATA": {
    "list": [
      {
        "val0": {
          "hidden": "0",
          "rate": "10"
        }
      },
      {
        "val1": {
          "hidden": "0",
          "rate": "20"
        }
      }
    ],
    "status": "Provisioned"
  }
}
```

I want to get the object name of `DATA>list>`. 
I tried with `get_class($list[0])` but the output is `stdClass`. Output should be `val0`.How can I try. Please help

Comment: decode the json and loop the array

Comment: `"Actually I want StdClass name.`" Please state the ultimate goal and remove from the question anything you don't "actually" want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `json_decode`, `list` is also an array, Therefor first key(0) represent `val0`, and If you want to get inner content of the `val0`, then you have to loop it again.

```
$data = '{
  "STATUS": "SUCCESS",
  "MESSAGE": "",
  "DATA": {
    "list": [
      {
        "val0": {
          "hidden": "0",
          "rate": "10"
        }
      },
      {
        "val1": {
          "hidden": "0",
          "rate": "20"
        }
      }
    ],
    "cpe_status": "Provisioned"
  }
}';

$data = json_decode($data, true);

foreach($data['DATA']['list'][0] as $key=>$value){
    echo $key; // return val0
    echo "<br/>";
    // to get val0 inner content
    foreach($value as $item=>$list){
        echo $item." - ".$list; // return val0 inner data
        echo "<br/>";   
    }
}

// alternative way for loop val0 inner content
foreach($data['DATA']['list'][0]['val0'] as $key=>$value){
    echo $key." - ".$value; // return val0 inner data
    echo "<br/>";   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Hopefully, the Self-Explanatory Snippet below could offer you a tip on how to go about doing it yourself. And by the way, you may [Quick-Test it Here](https://eval.in/683384).

```
<?php

        $strJson        = '{
                                      "STATUS"      : "SUCCESS",
                                      "MESSAGE"     : "",
                                      "DATA"        : {
                                                "list"  : [
                                                  {
                                                      "val0"    : {
                                                          "hidden"  : "0",
                                                          "rate"    : "10"
                                                        }
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                      "val1"    : {
                                                          "hidden"  : "0",
                                                          "rate"    : "20"
                                                       }
                                                }
                                                ],
                                            "cpe_status"  : "Provisioned"
                                      }
                             }';

        $objJson        = json_decode($strJson);
        $data           = $objJson->DATA;
        $lists          = $data->list;
        $list0          = $lists[0];
        $list1          = $lists[1];

        var_dump($lists);
```

> **The `var_dump($lists)` above yields::**

```
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[47]
              public 'val0' => 
                object(stdClass)[46]
                  public 'hidden' => string '0' (length=1)
                  public 'rate' => string '10' (length=2)
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[49]
              public 'val1' => 
                object(stdClass)[48]
                  public 'hidden' => string '0' (length=1)
                  public 'rate' => string '20' (length=2)
```

> Now, you can simply get all the data you want from the List using a simple loop like so:

```
<?php

        foreach($lists as $objList){
            if(is_object($objList)){
                foreach($objList as $key=>$data){
                    // NOW, YOU CAN DO SOMETHING WITH THE DATA...
                    // LIKE GET THE `hidden` OR `rate` PROPERTIES/ATTRIBUTES
                    $hidden     = $data->hidden;
                    $rate       = $data->rate;
                    // var_dump($hidden);
                    // var_dump($rate);
                    // var_dump($key);
                    var_dump($data);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: this is very cool but, as all other replies about similar topics, it works only for knonw JSON structure. What to do if one wants to print on each line the full "address" of an element of a JSON object?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$data = '{
                  "STATUS": "SUCCESS",
                  "MESSAGE": "",
                  "DATA": {
                    "list": [
                      {
                        "val0": {
                          "hidden": "0",
                          "rate": "10"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "val1": {
                          "hidden": "0",
                          "rate": "20"
                        }
                      }
                    ],
                    "status": "Provisioned"
                  }
                }';
        $data = json_decode($data); 

        $ss = $data->DATA->list;
        echo $ss[0]->val0->rate;
```